# MySql query combine results from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, join

I try to combine data from 2 tables by a mysql join but I look likes, I don't receive the results from the second table at all.

Table structre #1 (site_hosters);

```
+------------+--------------+--------+
| host_id    | name         | prio   |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 1          | site.com     | 0      |
+------------+--------------+--------+
```

Table structure #2 (site_date);

```
+------------+--------------+--------+
| id         | hoster       | page   |
+------------+--------------+--------+
| 1          | site.com     | http:..|
+------------+--------------+--------+
```

What I try to get is a result like 'id, host_id, name, ....etc';

When I try the follow query, it doesn't take host_id and prio in the query result.
It looks, the join has no effect at all by query it.

My query:

```
SELECT 
         site.id,
         site.hoster,
         site.page,

FROM site_data as site

INNER JOIN site_hosters hoster
ON site.hoster = hoster.name
```

I hope someone can help me with this one.

Kind regards,
Nick

Comment: because you are fetching result from one table only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to name the columns you want to select. Add the `site_hosters` columns like that:

```
SELECT 
     site.id,
     site.hoster,
     site.page,
     hoster.host_id,
     hoster.prio
FROM site_data as site
INNER JOIN site_hosters hoster ON site.hoster = hoster.name
```

Comment: Thanks, this works yes =).. I used the notation of BarsMedia, this because I use the query in a Sphinx config file, you can only use a break '/' on query key's.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
SELECT
           site.*,
           hoster.*
FROM site_data as site  
INNER JOIN site_hosters hoster ON site.hoster = hoster.name
```

This will return all fields, however, you may only want something like

`site.id, ste.hoster, site.page, hoster.prio` as your fields.

Answer (score 1):

Just list required fields in SELECT:

```
SELECT site.id, hoster.host_id, hoster.name, site.hoster, site.page
FROM site_data AS site
INNER JOIN site_hosters AS hoster ON site.hoster = hoster.name
```